# "undefined" variables and arguments

Tags: c++, function, parameters

I'm a student writing my first function, so I'm sure this will be an obvious error on my part.
On line 13 I'm getting an error in the parameter telling me that num1 and num2 are not defined. As I understand passing parameters, line 9 should be telling line 13 what num1 and num2 are (1 and 2). Since it's not working I'm clearly mistaken about how it works.

If someone could explain what I'm doing wrong, I'd appreciate the help. Thanks a bunch!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    Subtract(1, 2);
    return 0;
}

int Subtract(num1, num2) //num1 and num2 are undefined. 
{
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int x;
    x = num1 - num2;
    cout << x << "/n";
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What are the types on `num1` and `num2` ? (and why do you also have `num1` and `num2` local variables that will hide the parameters?

Comment: Unrelated to that particular error, but it will be the next one you'll have to bother with: In C++ everything needs to be declared before it is used. Here you are trying to use `Substract` in the line `Subtract(1, 2);`, but you only declare/define it later after `main`. That will give another error. Move the definition of `Substract` *before* `main`.

Answer (score 1):

Let me tell you issues in your code.

1. You need to tell the compiler what  num1 and num2 are.
2. Your code has one more drastic issue. You must know that mostly, the compiler goes line by line during compilation. So when he will reach in your main he doesn't know what is Subtract. You should tell him that it's a function otherwise it will be a compile-time error. Tip - Try to define every variable thing you wrote in your code. The compiler can't deduce anything by it's own.
3. As mentioned in a comment I found one more issue, to move in the next line you should write "\n"(it's backslash).

```
int Subtract(int , int); // This is must before main if you defined subtract later.
int main()
{
    Subtract(1, 2); // Compiler don't know what is subtract. As you defined Subtract later. The compiler doesn't know what is Subtract. To overcome this you need to declare a function before main.
    return 0;
}

int Subtract(int num1, int num2) // Here you need to tell that they are an integer. 
{
 //   int num1;
 ///   int num2; // once you told that num1 and num2 are an integer no need to do this. If you will try this. It will be a compile time error. As you already made num1 and num2 variable above. So can't declare variable twice.
    int x;
    x = num1 - num2;
    cout << x << "/n";
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Num1 and num2 are not defined and the one in function will mask the other one.

Comment: "*Num1 and num2 are not defined*" is just repeating the error message mentioned by OP and "*the one in function will mask the other one*" makes no sense in context, because as you said before, there was none defined until the definition in the function body. I don't see any way that this answer is helpful as it is. I suggest you expand on both points you are trying to make.